# How to insert/update data from one table into another table (postgresql)?

Tags: performance, postgresql, upsert

There are two tables

```
tmp_stat:
date, site_id, ip, block_id, count
Primary Key (date, site_id, ip, block_id)

main_stat:
date, site_id, ip, block_id, count
Primary Key (date, site_id, ip, block_id)
```

I need to 
insert rows into main_stat from tmp_stat when there are no such (date, site_id, etc)
and update count when they already exist
as quick as possible

tmp_stat contains about 500000 rows, main_stat contains millons

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1109061/330315

Comment: And see the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#i2081218

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name   I'd like to see an exmple with multi insert/update from table to table. I don't want to loop 500K rows, I hope there is more quick way to do that.

Comment: 2David: it's postgresql, not Oracle sql

Comment: Dimitri Fontaine recently did a write-up on batch update/insert in postgresql: http://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/03/15-batch-update.html. Perhaps that may be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm building on gsimes's answer as I understand the question.

```
with agg_temp_stat as (
    select date, site_id, ip, block_id, sum(counter)::integer counter
    from temp_stat
    group by 1, 2, 3, 4
), upd as (
    update main_stat t
    set counter = counter + s.counter
    from agg_tmp_stat s
    where
        (t.date, t.site_id, t.ip, t.block_id)
        = (s.date, s.site_id, s.ip, s.block_id)
    returning s.date, s.site_id, s.ip, s.block_id
)
insert into main_stat
select s.date, s.site_id, s.ip, s.block_id, s.counter
from
    agg_tmp_stat s 
    left join
    upd on
        upd.date = s.date 
        and upd.site_id = s.site_id 
        and upd.ip = s.ip 
        and upd.block_id = s.block_id
where upd.date is null
```

Basically aggregates the temp table and sums the resulting counter to the already existing one.

Answer (score 6):

Does the following work?

```
WITH upd AS (
    UPDATE main_stat t
       SET counter = s.counter
      FROM tmp_stat s
     WHERE t.date = s.date
            AND t.site_id = s.site_id
            AND t.ip = s.ip
            AND t.block_id = s.block_id
 RETURNING s.date, s.site_id, s.ip, s.block_id, s.counter
)
INSERT INTO main_stat
     SELECT s.mydate, s.site_id, s.ip, s.block_id, s.counter
       FROM tmp_stat s 
       LEFT JOIN upd ON (upd.date = s.date and  upd.site_id = s.site_id and upd.ip = s.ip and upd.block_id = s.block_id)
      WHERE upd.date IS NULL
;
```

**Update:**

It looks like this is only available for version 9.1 or newer.

Using just-somebody's suggestion of `WHERE (t.date, t.site_id, t.ip, t.block_id) = (s.date, s.site_id, s.ip, s.block_id)` appears to give better performance.

```
WITH upd AS (
    UPDATE main_stat t
       SET counter = s.counter
      FROM tmp_stat s
     WHERE ( t.date, t.site_id, t.ip, t.block_id ) = ( s.date, s.site_id, s.ip, s.block_id )
 RETURNING s.date, s.site_id, s.ip, s.block_id
)
INSERT INTO main_stat
     SELECT s.date, s.site_id, s.ip, s.block_id, s.counter
       FROM tmp_stat s 
       LEFT JOIN upd 
            ON ( upd.date = s.date 
                AND upd.site_id = s.site_id 
                AND upd.ip = s.ip 
                AND upd.block_id = s.block_id )
      WHERE upd.date IS NULL
;
```

What's happening here is we are using a CTE to do the UPDATE with the CTE returning the identifying columns for the updated rows.

The INSERT then uses the updated row information to filter tmp_stat to only insert the *new* records.

There are some concurrency caveats which Dimitri Fontaine covers in this [blog](http://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/03/15-batch-update.html) entry.

More information on CTEs can be found in the Postgresql [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/queries-with.html).

Comment: +1; i'd suggest `WHERE (t.date, t.site_id, t.ip, t.block_id) = (s.date, s.site_id, s.ip, s.block_id)` and `LEFT JOIN upd USING (date, site_id, ip, block_id)`.  or maybe `SELECT ... FROM tmp_stat s EXCEPT SELECT ... FROM upd`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like simple [Exists](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-subquery.html) query ... if the columns are indexed it should be fast enough.

exmple:

```
-- insert missing rows
INSERT INTO main_stat (date, site_id, ip, block_id)
SELECT date, site_id, ip, block_id FROM tmp_stat tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM main_stats main 
                           WHERE tmp.date    = main.date 
                           AND   tmp.site_id = main.site_id 
                           AND   tmp.ip      = main.ip
                           AND   tmp.block_id = main.block_id
                 );
-- update count for existing rows
UPDATE main_stat main 
SET count =  main.count + (SELECT count FROM tmp_stats tmp
                           WHERE tmp.date    = main.date 
                           AND   tmp.site_id = main.site_id 
                           AND   tmp.ip      = main.ip
                           AND   tmp.block_id = main.block_id
                           LIMIT 1)

WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM main_stats main 
                           WHERE tmp.date    = main.date 
                           AND   tmp.site_id = main.site_id 
                           AND   tmp.ip      = main.ip
                           AND   tmp.block_id = main.block_id
```